# in_array() doesn't work anymore as expected if the array is created with explode()

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

Firstly, I change my string to array. And when I try to search within that array can't search second array value. The below is my code.

```
//my string
$a = 'normal, admin';
//Change string to array
$arr = explode(",",$a);
// Search by array value
dd(in_array("admin", $arr)); //got false
```

But when I try to search something like the following, it's work.

```
//my string
$a = 'normal, admin';
//Change string to array
$arr = explode(",",$a);
// Search by array value
dd(in_array("normal", $arr)); //got true
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because value `admin` has a leading space from the `explode()`! 
You can see this if you do:

```
var_dump($arr);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "normal"
  [1]=>
  string(6) " admin"
       //^   ^ See here
}
```

To now solve this problem, simply apply [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) combined with [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to every array value like this:

```
$arr = array_map("trim", $arr);
```

Comment: `$arr = array_amp("trim", $arr);` is`$arr = array_map("trim", $arr);` ? It's work. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes the first one will not work as you can see there's an extra space before your `admin` that'll won't work need to use `trim` and `array_map` function before checking the result

```
$a = 'normal, admin';
//Change string to array

$arr = array_map('trim',explode(",",$a));
// Search by array value
var_dump($arr);
var_dump(in_array("admin", $arr));
```

output:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(6) "normal" [1]=> string(5) "admin" } bool(true)
```

Comment: @SetKyarWaLar you can accept one of these answers that'll make this answer to be considered as solved.Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You have an array from string like this:
You string:

```
$a = 'normal, admin';
```

After use of explode there will come any array like this:

```
$arr = array('normal',' admin');
```

I mean to say you have a space in admin that's why is not searching the admin in `in_array` function.

Solution: Before using the explode use this function:

```
$newstr = str_replace(" ", "", $a);
$arr = explode(',',$newstr);
```